# Unable to pass formatted Get-ADOrganizationlUnit output into function in script

Tags: powershell

I'm unable to pass the results of `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` into a function in a script.

I am storing the results in a variable that is being used to add the canonical name of the OUs returned by the cmdlet, to a dropdown list on a form.

I'm then attempting to use the same variable in a function that when called, will determine the distinguished of the OU based on the canonical name selected.

Since the variable is being set when the form loads so that the drop down in question will be populated with the various OUs, I added in a `write-output $myVar` just to make sure nothing strange was going on prior to being passed into the function. I've attempted to make `$myVar` global with `$Global:varName` and I've attempted to pass in the variable when calling the function: `myFunction $myVar $myVar1`. If I then use `write-output $myVar` within the function, there is no output, but I can use `write-host $myVar` and it will return a string of just the distinguishedNames of all the OUs in `$myVar`.

I tested this in the shell directly as well and I didn't have any issues with associating the canonical name back to the DN of the OU, but don't know what I'm doing incorrectly to cause it to not work when used in a script.

I'm using this to get the OU data for the dropdown list and function:

```bsh
$userOUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $ouRoot -Filter * -Properties CanonicalName | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*user*'}
```

Note: The dropdown list is populated successfully using `$userOUs`.

I call the function with a button:

```bsh
$myBtn.Add_Click({ myFunction $userID $userOUs})
```

The function I'm trying to pass it to:

```bsh
function myFunction($userID, $userOUs) {
            Write-Output $userOUs #returns nothing
            Write-Host $userOUs #returns the string containing all of the OUs' distinguished names

            $selectedOU = $OUList.SelectedItem
            $targetOUCanonicalName = "$domainPrefix$selectedOU" #I remove the domain name from the canonical name for display in the dropdown but add it back here
            $targetOu = $userOUs | Where-Object {$_.CanonicalName -eq $targetCanonicalName} | select -ExpandProperty distinguishedName 
            Get-ADUser -Identity $userID | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $targetOU

}
```

Ultimately, the goal is to be able to use the `$userOus` variable to determine the DN of the OU based on the selection made in a drop down of OU canonical names. I'd like to try and keep this more dynamic without having to define everything in a switch statement.

I expect once I get a bump in the right direction regarding why the variable is not passing into the function the way that I need it to, I'll be able to accomplish that.

Edit: I don't intend to use `write-host` or `write-output` since the script will have a form, I'm just using that to try and figure out what's going on.

Comment: Your function refers to `$OUList` and i don't see that defined anywhere. I think I would test that `$SelectedOU` outputs what you are expecting, first.

Comment: `$OUList` is where I populate the drop down list. It's just in my form code and is populated there. I just verified that `$selectedOU` does return the selected item in the dropdown list when the function is called though.

Comment: Does `$domainPrefix` contain the forward slash at the end of the string?

Comment: It does. If I copy paste the code where I set the variables, the function, and then call the function from the shell, the `$targetOU` is returned correctly, but when run as a script it's not. I assume that whatever is causing `write-output` to return nothing inside the function is the same reason for why I'm unable to set `$targetOU` properly.

Comment: If `write-host $userOUs` only returns a distinguished names list, then that will be problematic. `$userOUs` needs to be an AD OU object for the rest of your script to work because you are referencing properties that would be on an OU object of that type. E.g. `$UserOUs | where {$_.canonicalname -eq "something" }` won't ever find anything if you only have a list of DNs.

Comment: Right. when I set `$userOUs`, if I then run `write-output $userOUs`, I'm returned with a list of objects formatted as follows.... Pasting the results didn't work out with a comment for me, but it returns a list of object correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your version and it seems to work just fine:

```
function myFunction($userID, $userOUs) {
    Write-Output $userOUs #returns nothing
    Write-Host $userOUs #returns the string containing all of the OUs' distinguished names

    #$selectedOU = $OUList.SelectedItem
    #$targetOUCanonicalName = "$domainPrefix$selectedOU" #I remove the domain name from the canonical name for display in the dropdown but add it back here
    #$targetOu = $userOUs | Where-Object {$_.CanonicalName -eq $targetCanonicalName} | select -ExpandProperty distinguishedName
   # Get-ADUser -Identity $userID | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $targetOU

}

$userOUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties CanonicalName | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*user*' }
$userOUs

myFunction -userID $UserID -userOUs $userOUs
```

$UserOus display data for me, when I execute your function as above I also get output. The only thing that comes to mind is that the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: I made a couple very silly mistakes and when troubleshooting got hung up on the output issue. `$targetOu = $userOUs | Where-Object {$_.CanonicalName -eq $targetCanonicalName}` I attempted to select the DN from the CN using `$targetCanonicalName` but I set that information in `$targetOUCanonicalName`.......